What is wrong with my derivation of the formula relating the stored energy of a capacitor and its capacity and voltage?
I can't find where I'm doing a mistake here.
Let be two oppositely charged conductors, whose capacity $C= \frac{Q}{|\Delta V|}$ is well-defined. The potential on the positively charged plate is $V_+$ and on the negatively charged plate is $V_-$.
We have the energy $U$ satisfying: $$ U=\int QdV$$
$$ =\int C (V_+ - V_-)dV$$
$$ C \left(\frac{{{V_+ }^2}}{2}- \frac{{V_-}^2}{2} \right)$$
The result I find $U = C \left(\frac{{{V_+}^2}}{2}- \frac{{V_-}^2}{2} \right)$ is not the same as the one given in my class: $U = \frac{1}{2} C |\Delta V|^2$.
NB: I have read the meta.SE post about "ckeck-my-work questions, and what seems to have made a consensus (most upvoted answer) is that questions concerning conceptual mistakes (as opposed to questions involving arthmetical mistakes) are allowed / tolerated. My question is definitely not of the second category. I just want to learn.

You are trying to integrate $V_+$ and $V_-$ individually with respect to $V$ and this can't be done since they are independent variables.
However, you can integrate their difference $V_+ - V_-$ with respect to $V$ because $V=V_+ - V_-$, so
$\displaystyle \int C(V_+ - V_-) \space dV = \int CV \space dV = C \frac {V^2} 2$

Yes, by $V_+$ and $V_-$ I meant the voltage on the positively charged plate and the voltage on the negatively charged plate.

But the energy integral is not over $V_+$ or $V_-$ - it is over their difference $V$. You are trying to integrate $V_+$ and $V_-$ individually with respect to $V$, and this can't be done since they are independent variables.
